# Rounding issue in WooCommerce because of tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, tax

I added WooCommerce product prices excluding tax.

My client sent me a list of productprices including tax.
A product needs to be sold for €65,25 after adding tax.

The problem now is that it shows €65,24 after calculating tax. I want the prices to be €65,20 or €65,25 because it looks much cleaner. Is there any function that will create only steps of 5 cents.

I found this function but this will only work for the total price in cart. I want it for each product to do this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'my_custom_roundoff' );
function my_custom_roundoff( $total ) {
$round_num = round($total / 0.05) * 0.05;
$total = number_format($round_num, 2); // this is required for showing zero in the last decimal
return $total;
}
```