# Rounding WooCommerce subtotal doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding

I posted another question here: [Rounding issue in WooCommerce because of tax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67771266/rounding-issue-in-woocommerce-because-of-tax)

I solved this problem but in the cart and checkout the subtotal is still the old price (see this screenshot: https://ibb.co/gZB3q0S )

My code is like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    $round_num = round($price / 0.05) * 0.05;
    $price = number_format($round_num, 2);
    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'my_custom_roundoff' );
function my_custom_roundoff( $total ) {
    $round_num = round($total / 0.05) * 0.05;
    $total = number_format($round_num, 2);
    return $total;
}
```

How can I manage this for my subtotal?